# Image corners using border radius property in Safari / Chrome not formatted correctly

Tags: css, html, webkit

Working on my home page where I'm cycling through some images using JQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut methods.

The images have a border of 2px and a radius of 14px applied.

As you can see, the corners of the image are overlapping the border.

This behavior only happens in Safari and Chrome, not in Firefox and IE.

Anyone have any idea as to why?

You can see this behavior here:

http://www.findyourgeek.com/index-copy.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Support for `border-radius` on images in Chrome/Safari (or rather Webkit) seems to be a bit buggy

[Chrome -webkit-border-radius bug? - CSS-Tricks Forums](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11249/chrome-webkit-border-radius-bugs/p1)

The above post is from earlier in the year (~Chrome ver 10) when the support for `border-radius` on images wasn't working.  Support is available know but like you're seeing it still has some issues.  You may want to report the bug you're seeing to the Webkit/Chrome/Safari projects.  I know there was a fairly easy to find bug reporting page for Chromium, not sure about the other two.

Here are two ideas for workarounds:

1. you can apply sort of a CSS3 hack by removing the 2px `border` and setting a 2px stroke `box-shadow` (`box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #606060;`).  This would have a few drawbacks as it's only a fix for Chrome/Safari [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/T94Q4/)
2. or of course the other option is to edit the photos to give them rounded corners (http://www.roundpic.com/ is a good site for this)

Answer (score 0):

try removing the border styling from the image itself and adding it to #content #topStoriesTest

```
#content #topStoriesTest {

    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    height: 318px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 549px;
}
```